Wildcards for websocket URLs in Azure API Management service
I want to map a websocket endpoint from the API Management service to my underlying container.
The top-level URL is:
wss://rosieapiservice.azure-api.net/ws/CA1234237643 
Where everything after the /ws/ is a unique identifier for each unique websocket call.
For my underlying container service, the URL looks almost the same, but without secure websockets:
ws://rosie-demo.eastus.azurecontainer.io/ws/CA1234237643 
I have been able to connect to my websocket successfully, if I just use the portion without the variable ID:
wss://rosieapiservice.azure-api.net/ws/ 
But once I attempt to connect with the ID appended to the URL, I get a Status Code: 400 Bad Request.
I have tried to define a policy to handle the wildcards, per what I found in some of the documentation:
<inbound>
    <base />
    <set-backend-service base-url="wss://rosieapiservice.azure-api.net/ws/@(context.Request.Url.Path.Substring(context.Api.Path.Length + 4))" />
</inbound>

But that doesn't seem to help. Any pointers or suggestions on how to do this without having to modify the underlying code?

I believe, you want to amend the unique identifier value in the backend Url. Lets say, I have https://{instance_name}.azure-api.net/echo/CA1234237643  endpoint and I would be amending /ws/CA1234237643 in backend Url. I have used this URL for testing purpose as I don't have exposer to your endpoint.
I am using the below given policy to fulfil the requirement.
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-backend-service base-url="{Your_URL}" />
        <rewrite-uri template="@("/ws" + context.Request.Url.Path.Substring(context.Request.Url.Path.LastIndexOf('/')))" />
    </inbound>
</policies>

I am able to get the expected response as per the Trace.


I think the main issue here is that APIM does not allow wildcard paths for WebSockets, this only works with HTTP(S), but not for WS(S). APIM will throw an "InvalidWebsocketUpgrade" if the path is not exactly as specified in the API URL Suffix.
